# Submitting as Regular paper in same journal after receiving "revise before review" from special edition of the same journal?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, special-issue

I had submitted my paper to the special edition of the journal (due to relevance of work and faster processing timeline). Now I had received "revise before review" comment (they asked to provide graphs in high resoultion) which I have done. Along with that, the deadline for the special edition has been extended to 4 more months leading to additional 3 months time till first notification (a total of 7 months time). So, now my question is should I resubmit the "revised before review" version to the same special edition (considering the long time is it mandatory?) or I can submit as a regular paper (considering it will process faster?).

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Ask the journal, but you may have to withdraw from the special edition before resubmission. There is no guarantee this will save time, however.

Comment: Special Issues may often be run by different responsible editors. If you submit as regular paper, it may well be that the new editor starts the review process again from scratch. I'm not saying this is likely, but it's a possibility. Generally what your chances are that this runs faster as regular submission depends on the field and the journal. Personally I'd probably not risk the trouble for doing this, but you may be under more pressure to deliver fast publications than I am.

Comment: Thanks @Buffy .